# How to get URL Id inside serializers create method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following URL:

```
          url(r'^member/(?P<member_id>\d+_([\w-]+){22})/join/?$', views.ActivityJoinView.as_view(),
                       name='member_join'),
```

Within my DRF serializer `create` method I need to get access to `member_id`.

I have tried this:

```
class JoinListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Join
        fields = ("id", )


    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(self.context['request'].query_params)
```

I've also tried `validated_data.get('member_id', None)`

But still get bank/none! How can I get `member_id` inside my create method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside your `create` method you should be able to access the arguments passed to the view rendering your endpoint at

```
self.context['view'].kwargs.get('member_id')
```

Comment: That's a good one! Accessing kwargs inside the serializer is important.