# django restful api with nested objects in url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am try to expose an endpoint which looks like

/v1/organizaions/org1/members

so that I would be able to post to it and create a new member.
The member model has org_id field but I can't figure out how to hook up the ModelViewSet to populate the new member object's org_id with the id corresponding to org1.
Looking for some example code.

Here's what I did for the retrieval call:

```
class OrgMember(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Org.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrgSerializer

    def list(self, request, org_name):
        queryset = Member.objects.filter(org_id__org_name=org_name)
        serializer = MemberSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

So I'm looking for something similar for the create() method to lookup org_id by org_name and insert that into the serializer?

Comment: You should access the request object in your create() method and from that retrieve 'org_id'. Hope that helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577642/how-to-get-url-id-inside-serializers-create-method

Comment: Can you show your models as well please? If Member has a foreignkey to Org then why don't you do `Member.objects.filter(org__name=org_name)`? Or is it just the org_id field in Member.

Comment: @BriseBalloches yeah thanks. So i got the org_id and then injected it into data; it feels like a hack (especially because data is sometimes immutable for whatever reason...) . Is there no cleaner way?

Comment: @MK. not that i've heard of... It's how i currently work when i need to access request params from the serializer...